# Work permit update in Berlin/changing employer

Tags: visa, germany, working, employment

i lost my job end of June so i stayed July without a job. However in august I got a job that starts at the beginning of September. I immediately told migration office about the offer but also made an application to update my visa to have a new employer name since the first job i have only worked for nine months. My worries are can i start the new job even if i have not gotten the reply from the migration office yet?

Comment: What did your new employer say when you asked them?

Comment: Hi @Traveller the seem okay me to start then provide the authorization later